# OpenGL Matrix transformation not working

Tags: c, opengl, matrix

I am following the tutorials on learnopengl.com and I have come across an issues. I am writing my program in C rather than C++ and am using the linmath library for my matrix transformation and I have the files shader.c and texture.c. I believe that the issue is with my matrix transformation but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. The program runs and it compiles, the window is created and the background colour is correct however the object does not show.

Here is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "linmath.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include "texture.h"

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main(){
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL){
        printf("Failed to create GLFW window");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLAD");
        return -1;
    }
    Shader ourShader;
    ourShader.ID = loadShader("3.3.shader.vs", "3.3.shader.fs");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // colors           // texture coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    // top left 
    };     
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    Texture tex1 = loadTexture("container.jpg");
    Texture tex2 = loadTexture("awesomeface.png");

    // tell opengl for each sampler to which texture unit it belongs to (only has to be done once)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    useShader(ourShader.ID);
    setIntShader("texture1", 0, ourShader.ID);
    setIntShader("texture2", 1, ourShader.ID);


    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // bind textures on corresponding texture units
        bindTexture(tex1, GL_TEXTURE0);
        bindTexture(tex2, GL_TEXTURE1);

        // activate shader
        useShader(ourShader.ID);

        // create transformations
        mat4x4 model;
        mat4x4 m;
        mat4x4 view;
        mat4x4 projection;
        mat4x4_rotate(model, m, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.95993f);
        mat4x4_translate(view, 0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
        mat4x4_perspective(projection, 0.785f, (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // pass them to the shaders
        setMat4Shader("model", model, ourShader.ID);
        setMat4Shader("view", view, ourShader.ID);
        setMat4Shader("projection", projection, ourShader.ID);

        // render container
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

shader.c

```
#include "shader.h"

GLuint loadShader(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    char* VertexShaderCode;
    FILE * vertexFile = fopen(vertex_file_path, "r");
    if( vertexFile == NULL ){
        printf("Impossible to open the file !\n");
        return LOAD_FAILURE;
    }
    long vertex_file_size;
    fseek(vertexFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    vertex_file_size = ftell(vertexFile);
    rewind(vertexFile);
    VertexShaderCode = malloc((vertex_file_size + 1) * (sizeof(char)));
    fread(VertexShaderCode, sizeof(char), vertex_file_size, vertexFile);
    fclose(vertexFile);
    VertexShaderCode[vertex_file_size] = 0;

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    char* FragmentShaderCode;
    FILE * fragmentFile = fopen(fragment_file_path, "r");
    if( fragmentFile == NULL ){
        printf("Impossible to open the file !\n");
        return LOAD_FAILURE;
    }
    long fragment_file_size;
    fseek(fragmentFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    fragment_file_size = ftell(fragmentFile);
    rewind(fragmentFile);
    FragmentShaderCode = malloc((fragment_file_size + 1) * (sizeof(char)));
    fread(FragmentShaderCode, sizeof(char), fragment_file_size, fragmentFile);
    fclose(fragmentFile);
    FragmentShaderCode[fragment_file_size] = 0;


    const char* vsCode = VertexShaderCode;
    const char* fsCode = FragmentShaderCode;

    // 2. compile shaders
    unsigned int vertex, fragment;
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    // vertex shader
    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vsCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
    // fragment Shader
    fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fsCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment);
    checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
    // shader Program
    GLuint ID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
    glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
    glLinkProgram(ID);
    checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
    // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
    glDeleteShader(vertex);
    glDeleteShader(fragment);

    return ID;
}

void useShader(unsigned int ID){
    glUseProgram(ID);
}  

void setBoolShader(const char * name, int value, unsigned int ID)
{
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name), value);
}
void setIntShader(const char * name, int value, unsigned int ID) 
{
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name), value);
}
void setFloatShader(const char * name, float value, unsigned int ID)
{
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name), value);
}
void setMat4Shader(const char * name, mat4x4 mat, unsigned int ID)
{
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name), 1, GL_FALSE, *mat);
}

void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, char type[])
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[1024];
    if(strncmp(type, "PROGRAM", 7) != 0)
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
            printf("ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: %s \n %s \n", type, infoLog);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
            printf("ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: %s \n %s \n", type, infoLog);
        }
    }
}
```

texture.c

```
#include "texture.h"

Texture loadTexture(const char* path){
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // set the texture wrapping/filtering options (on the currently bound texture object)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    //load texture
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char *data = SOIL_load_image(path, &width, &height, &nrChannels, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    if(data){
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    } else{
        printf("Failed to load Image");
    }
    SOIL_free_image_data(data);

    Texture t;
    t.ID = texture;
    t.path = path;

    return t;
}

void bindTexture(Texture texture, GLenum unit){
    // bind textures on corresponding texture units
    glActiveTexture(unit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.ID);
}
```

vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture samplers
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main()
{
    // linearly interpolate between both textures (80% container, 20% awesomeface)
    FragColor = mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), texture(texture2, TexCoord), 0.2);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Doesn't it compile? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Hi Sorry I should have been more clear with that. It runs and creates a window with the color of the background specified however the object does not show

Comment: In this case it would be good to add the shader. And you should check whether they compile and link without errors.

Comment: I have added the vertex and fragment shader

Comment: There is also nothing wrong with the linking or compiling of the shaders.